Number of orbitals per atom in the electrode does not match the system electrode
I had the following question during transiesta calculation.
Number of orbitals per atom in the electrode does not match the system electrode
Have you changed your basis size?
Erroneous electrode setup, check out-put
Stopping Program from Node:    0
Erroneous electrode setup, check out-put
......

my input file for electrode calculation and part of input file for transiesta calculation are as following:
electrode
%include ELEC.fdf

PAO.BasisSize         DZP

XC.functional     GGA
XC.authors        PBE
MeshCutoff        300.000000 Ry
FilterCutoff      150.000000 Ry

ElectronicTemperature   300 K
OccupationFunction      FD

MinSCFIterations       3
MaxSCFIterations       200
SCF.DM.Tolerance       0.0001
# Mixing parameters:
SCF.Mixer.Weight       0.10
SCF.Mixer.History      12
SCF.Mix.First          true
DM.UseSaveDM           .true.
SCF.Mixer.Kick         0
SCF.Mixer.Kick.Weight  0.5
SCF.DM.Tolerance       0.0001

MD.NumCGSteps 0

#BandLinesScale ReciprocalLatticeVectors
#%block BandLines
#1   0 0   0
#100 0 0.5 0
#%endblock Bandlines

SaveHS                          T
#UseStructFile           true

transiesta
# This is the remaining default SIESTA options
PAO.BasisSize         DZP

XC.functional     GGA
XC.authors        PBE
MeshCutoff        300.000000 Ry
FilterCutoff      150.000000 Ry

ElectronicTemperature   300 K
OccupationFunction      FD
  
MinSCFIterations       3
MaxSCFIterations       200
SCF.DM.Tolerance       0.0001
# Mixing parameters:
SCF.Mixer.Weight       0.10
SCF.Mixer.History      12
SCF.Mix.First          true
DM.UseSaveDM           .true.
SCF.Mixer.Kick         0
SCF.Mixer.Kick.Weight  0.5
SCF.DM.Tolerance       0.0001

    
MD.NumCGSteps 0

SaveElectrostaticPotential T
SaveHS                          T
%include ../DEVICE.fdf

As you can see, I used %include to include atomic structures of electrode and device. In fact, these input files have succeed for other electrode and device calculations.

Here is the block %block ChemicalSpeciesLabel 〈None〉 for electrode
%block ChemicalSpecieslabel
1 79 Au
%endblock ChemicalSpecieslabel

Here is the block %block ChemicalSpeciesLabel 〈None〉 for device
%block ChemicalSpecieslabel
6 79 Au
......
%endblock ChemicalSpecieslabel

However,in the block %block  AtomicCoordinatesAndAtomicSpecies for device
I used a b c 1 instead of a b c 6,here, a b c is position of one gold atom.
That is the reason for the above error.
